# Get rectangles of a document with pdfclown

Tags: java, pdfclown

I´m using PDFClown to analyze PDF documents. Some documents have pages with rectangles like : [image]

Does pdfclown provide a function to work with these rectangles? For example to get there coordinates, length and width?

Comment: PDFClown allows access to all the instructions in content streams, so you can find the instructions drawing the rectangles. The problem is, though, that there are multiple ways to create the rectangles, so you should first determine the way those rectangles are created.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! You remind me that rectangles are a specific type of annotations (I dont have considered it before).  Thus I can iterate through each annotation of a page and check if this annotation is a rectangle! Sometimes I can´t see the wood for the threes.

Comment: If they are annotations in your case, great. One could add rectangles in the page content stream, too, though. So if they turn out not to be annotations, you'll have to scan the contents...

Comment: In my case all the rectangles I want to work with are annotations. But thanks for your information! I will keep it in mind if I have some problems!